# diff compare directories by filename only

Tags: linux, powershell, directory, diff

Is it possible to use any sort of diff utility to diff based on filename only, excluding the file extensions? I have multiple dirs that have various versions of a file, ie media.mov, media.mp4, media.jpg, etc. I want to make sure all versions were made for each file (1000s). So /dir1/media_99.mov and /dir2/media_99.mp4 would yield a TRUE condition. Man diff does not have "--ignore-extension" and I'm not sure how to possibly use "--exclude-from=FILE". I can use Linux (preferred) or PowerShell (if I must)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell, if you want to know which file names are unique to `/dir1`, use a [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) call, followed by reducing those file names to their base name (file name without extension), weeding out duplicates, and sorting via [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object)

```sh
Compare-Object -PassThru -Property Name (Get-ChildItem -File /dir1) (Get-ChildItem -File /dir2) |
  Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<=' |
    ForEach-Object BaseName |
      Sort-Object -Unique
```

Note: The assumption is that both `Get-ChildItem` calls return at least *one* file-info object, otherwise the `Compare-Object` call will fail - guard against that with `if` statements, if necessary.